# How can i not repeat a guess?

Tags: python

how can i brute force a password without repeating guesses, also without importing anything else? this is my code so far

```
import random
import string
guessAttempts = 0
myPassword = input("Enter a password for the computer to try and guess: ")
passwordLength = len(myPassword)
while True:
    guessAttempts = guessAttempts + 1
    passwordGuess = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)for n in range(passwordLength)])
    if passwordGuess == myPassword:
        print(passwordGuess)
        print("Password guessed successfully!")
        print("It took the computer %s guesses to guess your password." % (guessAttempts))
        break
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use a list to track your attemps

Comment: Use `itertools` to make a generator of all possible combinations for your pw scheme. This has the benefit of generating guesses on the fly, so you don't need a list of hundreds of thousands of passwords -- it will generate them one after another.

Comment: I agree with @Cheche, but use a `set` :)

Comment: Don't use random. The point of brute forcing is to try all possible combinations once, not unlimited random stuff

Comment: You enumerate the possible passwords, instead of hopping around randomly in the space of possible passwords. Otherwise, you need to store the passwords you've already tried,  which both uses (considerably) more memory, and doesn't solve the problem of *generating* repeat passwords.

Comment: Then do `if passwordGuess in attempted_passwords: continue`. You Will need to chance your counter to avoid incrementing if no attempt Is Made.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `n`-way product of `string.ascii_letters + string.digits` and iterate over it.

```
from itertools import product


passwords = map(''.join, product(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, repeat=n))
for (guessAttempts, passwordGuess) in enumerate(passwords, start=1):
    ...
```

`itertools` is in the standard library, so it's already installed whether you choose to use it or not: you may as well use it.